# AutoFill username with number pad keyboard seems broken in iOS 12 (works in iOS 11)

Tags: ios, autofill, ios12

My view has just 2 text fields, for username and password. Content type is specified accordingly. I want to use phone numbers as usernames, so I chose "Number Pad" as keyboard type for username field.

The issue is that when I run this on iOS 12, when first selecting username field, the autofill control does not appear above keyboard. If then select password field, it appears. Then I can select username field again and autofill control remains and is available this time.

If I change username keyboard type to default, the issue goes away.

In iOS 11 this issue does not exist.

Anyone knows why it is so?

Comment: @arash Yes, `Username` for first field, and `Password` for second one.

Comment: I would file a bug report at bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: I have the exact same issue.

Comment: This issue is still a thing two years later on iOS 14: When choosing [`.phonePad`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyboardtype/phonepad) as keyboard type for the [`.username`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view/) text field, the autofill toolbar will not be shown. [`.namePhonePad`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyboardtype/namephonepad) works, but is not a viable option if logins are phone numbers.

Comment: Almost four years later, and still an issue...

Comment: Same issue on iOS 16.0.2. I filed a bug report.